# Cannot allow local admins via GPO because of "Minimum password length" policy

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I need to enable local admin accounts on most of the computers. I have these passwords managed by LAPS, but I can't allow it with GPO when I have "Minimum password length" policy in place. Is there any workaround how to enable it via GPO without removing ""Minimum password length" policy? I don't want to allow these accounts with script. Thank you for every suggestion!

Comment: What happens? Is there an error?

Comment: I don't know... gpupdate runs without errors, "gpupdate /R" shows no errors, GPO is applied. I found this thread [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c7fba5b-c3eb-4ad1-bec6-e40ab6557512/enable-builtin-administrator-via-gpo-not-working?forum=winserverGP) so I have tried that and it's working with no "minimum password length" policy set...

Comment: What is the length of the account password and the minimum password length policy?

Comment: Maybe, there is a problem with LAPS and setting password on disabled account. I have minimum password length 10 characters and LAPS is showing me password for that account which is 20 characters long.

Comment: Does enabling the account manually work?

Comment: Why do you "need" to enable the local admin accounts? I can't think of a use-case where that would be required. If something needs to run as local admin, you're better off creating a service account and assigning that to Local Admin on each PC.

Comment: @GregAskew It does not work. I asked in a wrong way. Question should be something like "How can I set password on a dissabled account with LAPS" :) Problem is, that LAPS is behaving like there is the password set, but it's not... I have to enable that account and wait some time (without policy enforcing minimum password length). Then the password is really set. It looks like it's not possible to manage disabled accounts via LAPS :(

Comment: @Trix (1/2) I was expecting this question :) In some environments you need to have local admins allowed because of some policies. But ok. Except those policies, when I have technicians and those guys needs from time to time access some workstations with admin rights. Yes, I can create restricted group where I put priviledged accounts of those guys. Now, each account of that group is able to access every workstation in company...

Comment: @Trix (2/2) When there is local admin account enabled with strong password which is changed every week or faster, so this looks much more safer. There is different password on each PC and there is no need to mess with the computer, when there is corrupted trust with the domain. So... I don't know.... Maybe I forgot something...

Comment: `LAPS is behaving like there is the password set, but it's not... I have to enable that account and wait some time (without policy enforcing minimum password length). Then the password is really set.` That doesn't make sense. All you need to do to test is set the password, enable the account, then run gpupdate /force. LAPS should set the password and update the attribute on the computer account. There is also verbose logging that can be enabled for LAPS. Have you done that?